# findall duplicates

Tags: javascript

I keyed in my facts:

```
likesdrinking(tom).
likesdrinking(sally).
likesdrinking(holly).

likespainting(tom).
likespainting(sally).
likespainting(chad).
likespainting(margo).

likesskating(tom).
likesskating(holly).
likesskating(margo).
likesskating(matt).
likesskating(cass).
```

If I want to find those who likes drinking or painting or skating, i would use the findall method which is:

```
findall(X,(likesdrinking(X),likesskating(X),likespainting(X)),X).
```

and it will give me the result for those who likes more than once.
X= tom, sally, holly, tom, sally, chad .... etc

But how do I make it so that it will only return one answer instead of duplicates?
so it would be

```
X = tom, sally, holly, chad, margo, matt , cass
```

Comment: Actually, with your instruction you get those which like drinking AND skating AND painting. To get those matching one or more of the criteria use the OR separator `;` instead of the AND separator `,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the standard `setof/3` predicate:

```
?- setof(X, (likesdrinking(X),likesskating(X),likespainting(X)), L).
L = [tom].

?- setof(X, (likesdrinking(X),likesskating(X)), L).
L = [holly, tom].

?- setof(X, (likesdrinking(X),likespainting(X)), L).
L = [sally, tom].
```

As David noted in his comment, if you want to construct a list of people that like at least one those activities (without duplicates):

```
?- setof(X, (likesdrinking(X); likesskating(X); likespainting(X)), L).
L = [cass, chad, holly, margo, matt, sally, tom].
```

For questions like "who likes skating but not drinking", you have to be careful with the order of the goals. The following query is wrong:

```
?- setof(X, (\+ likesdrinking(X), likesskating(X)), L).
false.
```

Why? The variable `X` is not bound when you call `\+ likesdrinking(X)`, which will fail as there's several people that like drinking. You will need to write instead:

```
?- setof(X, (likesskating(X), \+ likesdrinking(X)), L).
L = [cass, margo, matt].
```

The `likesskating(X)` goal will bound `X` and then the `\+ likesdrinking(X)` will check that that specific person doesn't like drinking. In general, be careful when using the negation (`\+/1`) with non-ground goals.

Comment: And note that setof/3 _fails_ if it doesn't find anything (which is logically correct) whereas findall/3 unifies its third argument with the empty empty list (colloquially, "returns the empty list") if it finds nothing, which is breaks Prolog's "fail then redo" strategy and is more adapted to those stretches of code where you work non-logically.